# Android text on wallpaper

Tags: android, animation, text, wallpaper

I want to draw some text on the wallpaper and make it move, but on the wallpaper image. I know how to do it with `c.drawColor(int color)` in between the drawing of the moving text, but what can I do when I want to draw on a bitmap for example ? I should be able to use `c.setBitmap(Bitmap mBitmap)`, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Canvas.drawBitmap()`, draw the bitmap first and then draw the text.

`Cnavas.setBitmap()` is for setting a bitmap you created on memory using `Bitmap.createBitmap()`.